# PyQT QListWidget drag and drop does not work

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qlistwidget, realsense

I am trying to implement in my project a QListWidget with the possibility of moving elements by drag and drop

I try to integrate it into the project in the simplest way without success, while outside I have no problem executing it.

EDIT:The problem seems to come from the realsense library, without its, DAD works

Here is its implementation:

priorityContainer.py:

```
class priorityContainer(QListWidget):
def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()
    self.setIconSize(QSize(124, 124))
    self.setDragDropMode(QAbstractItemView.InternalMove)
    self.setDefaultDropAction(Qt.MoveAction) 
    self.setSelectionMode(QAbstractItemView.ExtendedSelection)
    self.setAcceptDrops(True)
    self.setDragEnabled(True)

    for i in range(5):
        QListWidgetItem( 'Item '+str(i), self)
```

main_interface.py:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
import traceback, sys, os
import pyrealsense2 as rs
from ressource.interface import priorityContainer


class UI_main(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(UI_main, self).__init__()

        self.setupUi()
        self.show()

    def setupUi(self):
        self.centralwidget = QWidget(self)
        self.mainVcontainer = QVBoxLayout(self.centralwidget)

        self.listWidget = priorityContainer.priorityContainer()

        self.mainVcontainer.addWidget(self.listWidget)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

    def root_path(self):
        return os.path.abspath(os.sep)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ui = UI_main()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Your question is unclear. What has the drag&drop to do with the rest of the code you provided? Please provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), otherwise we won't be able to understand anything.

Comment: I agree unfortunately the problem is there, if I use QListWidget in an isolate way I have no problem, it's context related. For example by removing the imports of other widgets, (and by commenting a good part of the text), I have no problem, it is enough to put these imports again and the problem returns.

Comment: As said, without a MRE we cannot help you (read the link in the first comment). Show us what you've done so far, even if it doesn't work as expected.

Comment: I can try to limit it, but there will be a lot of code anyway

Comment: @musicamante It's done, now i can see that the problem come from the realsense librairies

Comment: *What* problem?

Comment: I can't use drag and drop

Comment: Are you saying that just with that import statements, drag and drop does not work anymore, while if you comment it it does?

Comment: Exactly, it's that

Comment: See this bug report for librealsense: [Conflict with PyQT library](https://github.com/IntelRealSense/librealsense/issues/6174)

Comment: Oh thanks, this answer fix my problem

Answer (score 0):

I have solved my problem by adding these lines before any other imports where I import my pyrealsense2 librairies:

```
import sys
sys.coinit_flags = 2
import pythoncom
```

Reference to the fix: https://github.com/IntelRealSense/librealsense/issues/6174

Comment: You should add a reference to the bug report, which might be important for future reference.